# Python Pandas: Apply a value to groupby reult

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following data frames:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]})

   A  C
0  1  'x'
1  1  'x'
2  1  'x'
3  2  'y'
4  2  'y'
5  2  'y'
6  3  'z'
7  3  'z'
8  3  'z'

d2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':['a','b','c']})

0  a
1  b
2  c
```

I would like to apply the values of d2 to the groups of A and C of d1 so the resulting DF would look like this:

```
   A  C  B
0  1  x  a
1  1  x  a
2  1  x  a
3  2  y  b
4  2  y  b
5  2  y  b
6  3  z  c
7  3  z  c
8  3  z  c
```

How can I achieve this using Pandas?

Answer (score 4):

If possible you can use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `enumerate` object converted to dictionary:

```
d1['b'] = d1['A'].map(dict(enumerate(d2['B'], 1)))
print (d1)
   A  b
0  1  a
1  1  a
2  1  a
3  2  b
4  2  b
5  2  b
6  3  c
7  3  c
8  3  c
```

General solutions with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) for numeric values started by `0` and mapped to dictionary:

```
d = dict(zip(*pd.factorize(d2['B'])))

d1['B'] = pd.Series(pd.factorize(d1['A'])[0], index=d1.index).map(d)
#alternative
#d1['B'] = d1.groupby('A', sort=False).ngroup().map(d)
print (d1)
   A  B
0  1  a
1  1  a
2  1  a
3  2  b
4  2  b
5  2  b
6  3  c
7  3  c
8  3  c
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what happens if the groupby is made by more then one column?
I.E: the groups are A and another column C

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz - I suggest use `d1['B'] = d1.groupby(['A','C'] sort=False).ngroup().map(d)`

Answer (score 1):

To take duplicate categories in your `d2` into account, we will use `drop_duplicates` with `Series.map`:

```
values = d2['B'].drop_duplicates()
values.index = values.index + 1

d1['B'] = d1['A'].map(values)

   A  B
0  1  a
1  1  a
2  1  a
3  2  b
4  2  b
5  2  b
6  3  c
7  3  c
8  3  c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) here.

```
d2.index+=1
d1.merge(d2,left_on='A',right_index=True)

   A  B
0  1  a
1  1  a
2  1  a
3  2  b
4  2  b
5  2  b
6  3  c
7  3  c
8  3  c
```